# How to pass array/function to view page ? [OC]

Tags: php, mysql, opencart

Currently in my file

controller/common/home.php

```
$this->load->model('catalog/category');
$homepageProductTest = $this->model_catalog_category->homepageProductTest();
```

And when i echo $homepageProductTest , there is bunch of array.

What i wanted:
How do i pass the variable to my view file (home.tpl)

The error i always get (view/theme/xxx/template/common/home.tpl)

> Undefined variable: homepageProductTest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to use any variable in your view file from controller file then you have to pass your value in  `data`  variable like below,

like in your case, you want "homepageProductTest"

```
$data['homepageProductTest'] = $homepageProductTest; //write this code in your controller file
```

OR

```
$this->data['homepageProductTest'] = $homepageProductTest; //write this code in your controller
```

in .tpl file you can use this variable using PHP like,

```
<?php foreach($homepageProductTest as $producttest){ ?>
  //your code here
<?php } ?>
```